Creating a JUCE Plugin Package Installer for Distribution to Other Macs
I am having quite a bit of trouble with creating a plugin package installer that I can send to other people and have successfully downloaded on other computers. I am an Apple Developer and I was able to create both a Developer ID Installer and a Developer ID Application certificate. I added them to Keychain Access. While I was able to sign the actual AU .component itself, I am running into problems signing the package installer. When I examine the Developer ID Installer certificate, the Evaluation Status is set to "Invalid Extended Key Usage" which I presume is causing my issue? Is there any way to change this Evaluation Status and am I overlooking anything in this process?
In addition, I was having trouble deleting the actual Developer ID Installer certificate and creating a new one using the Apple Developer program. I am still seeing the same Evaluation Status for my certificate ("Invalid Extended Key Usage").
